# Javascript, GetElementById element is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

For some reasons, I can't display #coupon with javascript, when i try to get elementById it displays the error message elementById undefined,

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exercise</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="inputi">
    <p class="input-text">Une Jam?</p> <input placeholder="Sheno emrin..." type="text" id="inputId">

    //checks input value
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue()">Vazhdo</button>
    // shows error message if it doesn't match the array
  <p id="message"></p>
  </div>


    // i want to display this with javascript, after the login
    <h1 id="coupon">You won giftcard </strong></h1>
    <button id="coupon">abas</button>

 


</body>

</html>
```

JS ( the problem )

**
**the problem** getElementById is undefined, I want to display:block after the successful login attempt.
**

```
      var zzz = getElementById("coupon")
      if(zzz === "none") {
      display:block; }
 

    
      
      // document.writeln("<h1>Keni fituar kupon 50% ne <strong> Green & Protein </strong> </h1>");
      
      // document.writeln('<input class="giftcode" placeholder="' +finalcode+'" type="text" id="inputId">');
      display_image(images[z], 400, 400, 'Javascript');
      document.write('<br>' + user[i]);

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Not the main issue you are having, but `id`'s should be unique within a document. You are having two elements with the same `coupon` id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code above it shows that you're trying to call a method getElementById() which you have not yet defined.

2ndly, you can only assign only 1 id in a document else it will not work.

you can do something like this

// i want to display this with javascript, after the login

```
<span id="coupon" style="display: none">
   <h1>You won giftcard </strong></h1>
   <button>abas</button>
</span>
```

what you meant to call is document.getElementById("coupon"); which is the right function to do.

so try this;

`var zzz = document.getElementById("coupon");`

i don't really know what your criteria is for a successful login but this show help
let say you set a variable as `var success = "yes"` on successful login

```
if(success === "yes"){
zzz.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`
- you need to move your script tag to the bottom of the `body` tag to ensure that the element is in the DOM when you select it

Use:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Exercise</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="inputi">
         <p class="input-text">Une Jam?</p>
         <input placeholder="Sheno emrin..." type="text" id="inputId">
         //checks input value
         <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue()">Vazhdo</button>
         // shows error message if it doesn't match the array
         <p id="message"></p>
      </div>
      // i want to display this with javascript, after the login
      <h1 id="coupon">You won giftcard </h1>
      <button id="coupon">abas</button>
      <script src="javascript.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: var element = document.getElementById("coupon");
        if( element.style.display === " none") {
         element.style.display = "block"
        }  // this still gives me an error

Comment: @samgear Can't reproduce the error. Make sure you've moved the `script` tag to the bottom of the `body`. See the code block in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call `document.getElementById` instead. Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 1):

Try: document.getElementById
Instead of : getElementById

Because getElementById is a document method